# SolrCloud deployment for high frequency traffic

Tags: solr, bigdata, solrcloud

We have been looking for a big data storage which can collect a huge pool of user information.

Also, I would like to mention that we are working on RTB platform (namely DSP side). As a result, our platform handles around 100 millions of requests per day. It is about 1-2 thousands of requests per second (depends on time). Here is a simple overview what we are going to implement:

[image]

My questions are:

1. Is it a good solution using Solr (SolrCloud) in Data Management Platform?
2. How do you think whether SolrCloud can handle high frequency traffic?
3. I have checked [Solr performance problem](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceProblems#Slow_commits) and there is one option - extremely frequent commits (under Slow commits item). What is the limit?
4. What configuration of SolrCloud will be suitable for us? I mean amount of shards, cores and server configuration (CPU, RAM) to handle 1-2K QPS and store about 500M docs. How can we calculate this?

Comment: How often do you need to refresh the data available for querying? (i.e. can you commit each 10 seconds instead of after each update?)

Comment: @MatsLindh yes, we can do it easily (up to 1 minute) but I am afraid that size of commit will be about 10 MB and even more

Comment: That probably won't be an issue - comitting often is far worse, as that is what persists objects and reopen searchers. And regarding QPS - your query types will be far more important considering how you'll scale. In general, it's very hard to predict these things for someone outside your organization without doing a proper planning project and some testing. There is nothing inherent in your problem that wouldn't work with Solr or another Lucene based technology.

Comment: @MatsLindh, "proper planning project and some testing" unfortunately we do not have enough resources to test SolrCloud on 10 servers and use 20 shards for example. I am trying to find a proper deployment setting for our future case (question #4)

Comment: As I said, that's impossible to say without having a lot more details about your use case. You could make it work with a single node with proper caching, or you could need a lot of servers. My point is that the _workload and specific requirements for your application_ will define what kind of infrastructure is necessary.